# Tornado static file routing

Tags: html, css, resources, tornado

I'm trying to prepare a default error page. In `error.html` file I use:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In tornado `Application` I use following routing instruction:

```
(r'/css/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'assets/css'}
```

Let's say I type `http://localhost:8888/api` url. Everything is fine and css file is loading correctly and error page is rendered fine. However when I type `http://localhost:8888/api/foo` the css file is not found.

In the first situation the css request `http://localhost:8888/css/bootstrap.min.css` is handled correctly by the handler. In the second approach the request for css is translated to `http://localhost:8888/api/css/bootstrap.min.css` which is not handled.

I want the resources to be found in both situations to correctly display error page. I can use:

```
(r'.*/css/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'assets/css'}
```

However this time I can type into browser `http://localhost:8888/api/asdasdsadsad/css/bootstrap.min.css` url and the css file is dispayed while I think there should displayed error page. How may I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use relative paths. There are two common ways to fix this:

1. use absolute urls. Add `/` (slash) before any resource, so instead of `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` use `<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
2. add [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) to page in `<head>` section

   > Base ... specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document.

   `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`

And leave the handler as

```
(r'/css/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'assets/css'})
```

the latter is working because it's regex is very broad, as you notice it handles request that should be `404`. The good practice is to have routes as specific as possible.

Comment: I was trying your first solution before and it didn;t work, however it does now. Thanks for help and second example which was something new for me.